# Populate a DefaultMutableTreeNode from database

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtree, treenode

I am fairly new to Java and I want to create a DefaultMutableTreeNode class that contains Map objects.

I wrote a TreeNodeMap class that inherits from a more generic TreeNode class which in turn inherits from DefaultMutableTreeNode.

The TreeNodeMap class contains the method *populate* that takes a rather long list of parameters. I plan to improve the methods readability by converting some of those parameters into a single object and overloading the method so that I don't have to pass a set of nulls in the first call (is recursive).

Note:*If you don't care for my verbose explanation of the method skip directly to the code from here*

Initially I create an empty node that will only contain children but no data, this is ROOT. The idea is to have a method that allows the caller to pass any query with 'field_id', 'field_label', 'parent_id' columns. On the initial call the query is passed with a Where clause where the 'parent_id is null' hence getting all nodes with no parent. All these nodes are added to the ROOT node. While iterating over the Resultset the *populate* method for each node is called passing now a 'Where clause' where parent_id = [current node id] hence getting all the children for that node. This will happen recursively until all nodes are created with a hierarchy.

*code*
(Remember, I'm new to JAVA so any feedback is appreciated)

```
public void populate( boolean isRoot, String parentFieldId, String parentFieldLabel, String childFieldId, String childFieldLabel, 
            int parentId, String tableName, String whereClause, String orderByClause, String additionalColumns, List<Map<String, String>> queryParams) throws SQLException, Exception{
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try{

            DBConnection dbConnection = new DBConnection("localhost", 3306, "root", "password", "test", DBDrivers.DBTYPE_MYSQL);
            con = dbConnection.getConnection();

            String treeNodeSql = "Select " + parentFieldId + ", " + parentFieldLabel + 
                                                ", " + childFieldId + ", " + childFieldLabel;
            if(additionalColumns != null && additionalColumns.trim().length() > 0)
                treeNodeSql +=  " ," + additionalColumns;

            treeNodeSql += " From " + tableName + " WHERE 1=1";

            if(whereClause != null && whereClause.trim().length() > 0 ){
                treeNodeSql += " AND " + whereClause;
            }

            if(isRoot){
                treeNodeSql += " AND " + parentFieldId + " is null";
            }else{
                if(parentFieldId == null || parentFieldId.trim().length() == 0)
                    throw new Exception(" The populate() method requires a parentId when isRoot is false.");
                treeNodeSql += " AND " + parentFieldId + " = ?";
            }
                //order clause append
            if(orderByClause != null && orderByClause.trim().length() > 0)
                treeNodeSql += " " + orderByClause;

                //prepare statement
             ps = con.prepareStatement(treeNodeSql); 
            int ixParam = 0;

                for(Map qParam : queryParams){
                    if(qParam.get("datatype") == "int"){
                        ps.setInt(++ixParam, Integer.parseInt((String) qParam.get("value")));
                    }else if(qParam.get("datatype") == "string"){
                        ps.setString(++ixParam, (String) qParam.get("value"));
                    }
                }

            out.println(treeNodeSql);
            if(parentId > 0){
                ps.setInt(queryParams.size()+1, parentId);
            }
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
                HashMap<String, Object> childNodeData = new HashMap<String, Object>(4);
                childNodeData.put("parentFieldId", parentFieldId);
                childNodeData.put("parentFieldIdValue", Integer.toString(rs.getInt(parentFieldId)));
                childNodeData.put("parentFieldLabel", parentFieldLabel);
                childNodeData.put("parentFieldLabelValue", rs.getString(parentFieldLabel));
                childNodeData.put("childFieldId", childFieldId);
                childNodeData.put("childFieldIdValue", Integer.toString(rs.getInt(childFieldId)));
                childNodeData.put("childFieldLabel", childFieldLabel);
                childNodeData.put("childFieldLabelValue", rs.getString(childFieldLabel));

                out.println("parentId: " + rs.getInt(parentFieldId)
                                + ", parentLabel: " + rs.getString(parentFieldLabel)
                                + ", childId: " + rs.getInt(childFieldId)
                                + ", childLabel: " + rs.getString(childFieldLabel));
                TreeNodeMap childNode = new TreeNodeMap(childNodeData);
                this.add(childNode);
                childNode.populate(false, parentFieldId, parentFieldLabel, childFieldId, childFieldLabel, rs.getInt(childFieldId), tableName, whereClause, orderByClause, additionalColumns, queryParams);
            }
        }catch(SQLException e){
            throw e;

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            out.println(e.getCause());
            out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }finally {
            try { rs.close(); } catch (Exception e) {  }
            try { ps.close(); } catch (Exception e) {  }
            try { con.close(); } catch (Exception e) {  }
        }
    }
```

The initial call to the method looks something like this:

```
treeNode.populate(true, "supervisor_id", "supervisor", "employee_id", "employee", 0, "vw_employee", null, null, null, queryParams);
```

The problem I see with this approach is that the DB will be queried X amount of times and with a big data set I'd think this will cause some problems. I'm also opening a connection For each query! So I thought about passing the Connection to the method once it was created (in the recursive calls), but then I'm not sure how to close it appropriately. I could write a conditional to check if the node is the ROOT, then close the connection but then what happens if the code fails in between.

So FINALLY my questions:
1- What's the best way to approach this?
2- Should I pass the connection around so that only one connection remains open during the population of the tree? If Yes, then how do I close it properly.
3- Should I cache the Resultset into an ArrayList and use that instead?

Answer (score 3):

Your performance concern may be warranted. Instead,

1. Implement `TreeModel`, as shown in this [`FileTreeModel`](https://dzone.com/articles/taking-new-swing-tree-table-a-). In this way, only visible nodes need be queried. There's a related example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/implementsTreeModeltocreatetreemodel.htm).
2. Pass `javax.sql.DataSource`, rather than `Connection`.
3. Your class that `implements TreeModel` can encapsulate any cached data, but also provide some means to update stale entries. After displaying cached values, consider using `SwingWorker` to refresh the model, as shown [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/6692). Instead of `List<Record>`, you might want to look at `Map<PrimaryKey, Record>`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice @trashgod. There are several things to digest here and I'm already looking at your suggestions.
I wasn't aware of the javax.sql.Datasource, seems to be doing the same I was doing with my DBConnection class and there's no need to reinvent the wheel so most likely I'll use that one.

I'll continue reading and get back to you once I understand all your suggestions. 

Thanks again!